# best approach to open a pop up window for large data

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

i am new to wpf and i need to open up a pop up a new window on grid row click which contains lots of  data and controls on it.i am confused with the correct approach. i am using mvvm pattern.should i make a window control or user control or something else. and how to open that pop up inside a function. please help with example

Comment: Should the new window close automatically if the user selects a new row? or should the user explizit close it?

Comment: explicit close it

Comment: then see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I need to display a new `Window` in my MVVM-Application I use the following approach:

At first I have an interface with a method to show the new dialog:

```
internal interface IDialogManager
{
  void DisplayData(object data);
}
```

And an implementation like:

```
internal class DialogManager : IDialogManager
{
  public void DisplayData(object data)
  {
    LotOfDataViewModel lotOfDataViewModel = new LotOfDataViewModel(data);
    LotOfDataView lotOfDataView = new LotOfDataView
    {
      DataContext = lotOfDataViewModel
    };
    lotOfDataView.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

LotOfDataViewModel and LotOfDataView are the new Dialog where you want to show your data.

In your actual ViewModel you introduce a new property like:

```
private IDialogManager dialogManager;
private IDialogManager DialogManager
{
  get { return dialogManager ?? (dialogManager = new DialogManager()); }
}
```

And the you can show your large data with:

```
DialogManager.DisplayData(myData);
```